# Delete a LinearLayout on long press event

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am creating a `LinearLayout` dynamically. I need to delete the `LinearLayout` on `LongPress` event.

My code :

```
public void addTileView(View v) {         
      _parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridCont); 

    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtileview,null);
     ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.tileText)).setText("Tile View :"+_tileViewCount++);       
    _parentLayout.addView(child);       
    _parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
public void addTileView(View v) {

      _parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridCont);

      child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtileview,null);
     ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.tileText)).setText("Tile View :"+_tileViewCount++);



    _parentLayout.addView(child);

    child.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            _parentLayout.removeView(v);
            return true;
        }
    });



}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
_parentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           parentLayout.removeAllViews();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It will remove the parent too. I need to remove that specified View on which longpress event triggered .

Comment: child.removeAllViews() i don't no it will work or not. just try it. i hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

Its better to remove the view which you added in the parent .
Say Parent layout is the main layout and child layout is the one which you want to remove.
You should try 
parent_layout.removeView(child_layout);

removeAllViews() - will remove all the views inside the view , but not the main view .

Please refer to ViewGroup 
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(myView.getParent());
vg.removeView(myView);

Alternatively , You can make the visibility of your view to Visible.GONE , and then make it visible when required.